# Is this method of “burial” possible?

Tags: internal-consistency, space, moons, flora, planets

Now that colonization of Mars and The Moon is starting to pick up, lots more people will start dying. LifeHarbor Burials™ says that they will provide a way to dispose of the dead for free.

They claim that after you die, they put some seeds of your choice and some dirt into your suit with you, and then “your suit will always harbor life, even after death”. Apparently they strip the expensive components from the suits to cover the costs.

Well, I don’t buy it. The light let in from the helmet would only cover a small amount inside the suit, and on Mars there is much less sun to start with. Not to mention the moon has 2 weeks of darkness.

So, is what LifeHarbor Burials™ is claiming really possible?

Answer (score 4):

## Not...Exactly:

If you really want to get technical, then if they put Earth soil into your suit, they are likely depositing a few desiccation-resistant spores which might survive. But at the humidity and temperatures on Mars currently, nothing is going to grow. Just as the potatoes were dead and unable to grow in the movie *The Martian* after the agri-dome ruptured, those seeds would be deep-frozen and unable to grow. They would likely be permanently damaged by the deep-freeze and unable to ever grow. Not to mention that the suit would be sealed, and even if the outside temperatures were warm enough (as they very rarely are at the equator) the oxygen supply would quickly exhaust and only anaerobic fermentation by bacteria would be possible in the suit.

If they took your body out of your suit, buried it in a domed garden, and did the same thing, then your body would be fertilizer. Or if they dumped your body into a composter, you'd be rendered down even faster and more efficiently. Then you would truly be reentering the life cycle of imported life. If Mars were significantly terraformed, and if the suit were composed of biodegradable materials, then it would be *possible* this could work.

Comment: That is an issue I did not think of, space has very extreme temperatures.

Comment: Agree (and upvoted) and suggest adding that the suit will not retain atmosphere for particularly long either, as described in https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23658/whats-the-normal-leakage-rate-for-a-space-suit

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it doesn't take into account what happens to the body on decomposition. (Which is on-the-whole very nasty, and produces lots of toxic components which would scorch the plants.)

Answer (score 1):

### I do not think so

Environment around is hostile to live. Even if the suit is ideal isolator and the light thru helm is good power source (both unrealistic, even when the burial would somehow change the suit to fit its new purpose), then single seed would live only so long, before all chemicals inside is consumed.

You would need much more elaborated biosystem to survive **forever** in such small and restricted place, recycling all chemicals forever and forever. And it hardly would be a single plant in any reasonable meaning.

Even something like bactery colony (bleah) would over time die in its own waste.

I bet they will run some shenigans, where somethings live inside the suit for long enougth so

- relatives would forget it (or die)
- terraformation would take place and the rest would be buried in open land, forming forrest (and the trees would not be individually distinctive)
- the company end exist and so it does not care
- (they will do some trick like a year later, where they put plastic/holografic model of plant inside, powered by fotovoltaitic pannels on the suit and get rid of your remains by some less official way)

---

Anyway **forever** is too long to your suit would exist so long (well too long for even Sun exist so long, if we are at it)

Answer (score 0):

## Who needs light anyway

Replace plant seeds with fungi spores. Problem solved.

And if you are doing it with psilocybin mushrooms, sign me up. That would make death THE ultimate trip.

On a more serious note, this idea will only ever fly if Mars has been terraformed, whether with plants or fungi. They just wouldn't survive indefinitely inside a suit, nor in Mars super dry, barren landscape. The Moon is even worse. If terraforming has not been done, at the very least you need to die in a dumpster under a pressurized dome.

Comment: Fungi will only last until they use up the available bio energy in the dearly departed.  Also, psilocybin comes in three basic types based on what they grow on: wood, dung, and decaying vegetable mattter. They don't do well on dead flesh. There are some fungi that do so, but they are usually not amusing in the way psilocybin is.